# Java stream map modifies custom class object not built in classes

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
class Employee {

    public String name;
    public Integer age;
    public Employee(String n, int age) {
        this.name = n;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.name+":"+this.age;
    }
}
```

Inside Main:

```
ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Employee("NameA", 10));
list.add(new Employee("NameB", 25));
list.add(new Employee("NameC", 30));
list.add(new Employee("NameD", 45));
list.add(new Employee("NameE", 50));

System.out.println(list);//[NameA:10, NameB:25, NameC:30, NameD:45, NameE:50]

list.stream().filter(e->e.age%10==0).map(e->e.name+="CHANGE").collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list); //[NameACHANGE:10, NameB:25, NameCCHANGE:30, NameD:45, NameECHANGE:50]


ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
strList.add("1");
strList.add("2");
strList.add("3");
strList.add("4");
strList.add("5");

System.out.println(strList);//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

List<String> updatedStrList = strList.stream().map(s->s+="CHANGE").collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(updatedStrList);//[1CHANGE, 2CHANGE, 3CHANGE, 4CHANGE, 5CHANGE]

System.out.println(strList);//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What's the reason for this behaviour?
When the Employee object's value is being changed the value gets updated in the original ArrayList but when ArrayList of String was changed the values did not reflect in the original ArrayList.

Comment: The function passed to map() is not supposed to modify what it maps. It's supposed to return an other object from the object it takes as argument (what your second example, using strings, does). `s += "CHANGE"` doesn't modify `s`. It created a new String which is the concatenation of `s` and "CHANGE".

Comment: Calling `collect(Collectors.toList())` without capturing the return value is a waste of resources.

Comment: stream().map() lets you convert an object to something else. Take a look of this article https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-map-examples/ .

Comment: The javadoc of [`map(mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) explicitly states that the  mapper must be *"a [non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) function"*. You're violating the non-interfering part of the contract when you update the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a different between `e.name+="CHANGE"` and `s->s+="CHANGE"`. Both of them create a new `String` instance, but while the first assigns that new `String` to an instance variable of an instance of the `Employee` class (and therefore mutates that instance), the second assigns it to a local `String` variable.

Therefore `e.name+="CHANGE"` changes the corresponding instance of the original `List` and `s->s+="CHANGE"` doesn't.

Comment: So the map function returns a new stream and in the first example since the Employee object's member value was changed it was reflecting in the original list but the same did not happen in the second case, right?

I think I got it, thank you.

Comment: @GagandeepSingh yes, the `map` method returns a new `Stream` with new `String` elements. And yes, in the first example you are modifying `Employee` elements of the original `Stream` (which also affects the original `List`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with streams.

In this lambda expression: `s -> s += "CHANGE"`, you're just reassigning the local variable `s`. `s += "CHANGE"` also returns the result of the concatenation, and that explains why the stream shows the mapped value. This reassignment is only effective in the local scope of the lambda expression.

But `e.name+="CHANGE"` updates the field of the `Employee` object `e`. This updates the original object itself.

You should collect mapped values instead of updating original stream elements. Incidentally, updating original stream elements is not even an option in your case because you can't modify String objects.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this up, I understand the concept now.